# Setting network activity indicator is deprecated

Tags: ios, ios13

I just found that `UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623102-isnetworkactivityindicatorvisibl), but no alternative property or method is suggested to be used. I assume that iOS will handle showing and hiding network activity indicator starting from iOS 13.

Would someone who has iOS 13 Beta verify or deny this assumption?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I tested this on iOS 13 beta and nothing was shown in the status bar while performing a network activity. So the network activity indicator probably will not be displayed from iOS 13. The deprecation message says:

> Provide a custom network activity UI in your app if desired.

Also note that the network activity indicator used to display on devices without edge-to-edge displays only.

Comment: A couple years late to the party, but this is official in Apple's HIG now: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/progress-indicators/